# Distribute computing on multiple devices

Tags: java, machine-learning, bigdata, distributed-computing

My project takes very long time at running,
I made threads and distributed data and processing on my processor cores,
But, still takes long time,
I tried to optimize the code as i can,
How can i distribute computing on multiple laptops?

Comment: 50 MB and im making natural language processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your four keywords :
`java`, `machine-learning`, `bigdata` and `distributed-computing` I come down to conclusion that you want something like `hadoop`.

its a perfect choice for `natural processing` too.

then again I don't have any details of your problem, but you'll be surprised what hadoop can do.

alternatviely for ease of use you may want to look at cloud computing such as [WatsonAnalytics](http://www.ibm.com/analytics/watson-analytics/)

Answer (score 2):

You may look at `Java MPI` which supports MPICH2 API.
Also I've heard of distributed JVM support from Terracotta.

Without knowing the low level view of your requirement/application its hard to suggest a working method.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your processing requirements. If its some mathematical computation that needs to be done on some dataset your machine is not able to process quickly, you can make batches and send it to different machines simultaneously and poll for the results from each. There are async operations available in multiple languages, that you can utilize to send (either the location of batches or the batches them self) to multiple machines.